# How to convert string to X509Certificate

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509certificate, x509

I am writing a powershell script which needs to take a string and convert it to a file certificate.cer

For example, here's a part of an XML file which I want to parse

```
-<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>MIIC8DCCAdigAwIBAgIQd6hiMdvxR4JAxJeGxPaLBTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA0MTIwMAYDVQQDEylNa(...)</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
```

I want to grab this long string MIIC8DCCAdigAwIBAgIQd6hiMdvxR4JAxJeGxPaLBTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA0MTIwMAYDVQQDEylNa(...) and save it as a certificate.cer file - I searched on the internet but haven't found an exact method. How can I do   do that in Powershell only?

Comment: `[X509Certificate]::new([convert]::FromBase64String('MIIC8DCCAdig...'))`

Comment: unfortunately, I am getting this error: Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid length for
a Base-64 char array.
At line:1 char:1
+ [X509Certificate]::new([convert]::FromBase64String('MIIC8DCCAdigAwIBA ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: I have doubts it is a base64 string. It's a valid cert string however. Because when i open the cert which i can download manually from the portal and open it in notepad it is the same string (but divided in lines and not a single line).

Comment: You may have to add base64 padding.

Comment: No conversion is necessary, just save that Base64 string into your .cer file with header and footer: `'-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----' | Out-File -FilePath .\certificate.cer; 
'MIIC8DCCAdigAwIBAgIQd6hiMdvxR4JAxJeGxPaLBTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA0MTIwMAYDVQQDEylNa(...)' | Out-File -FilePath .\certificate.cer -Append; 
'-----END CERTIFICATE-----' | Out-File -FilePath .\certificate.cer -Append;`

Comment: @leeharvey1 `Out-File` in PowerShell version 7.x default to encoding `utf8NoBOM`, while earlier versions default to writing files in `Unicode` (UTF16-LE) encoding. This may present an error.

Comment: @Theo True.  Adjust encoding, as needed.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Saving the string to a file via Out-File with UTF8 encoding does work. Can you suggest a method to prepare the file in memory? I will be using it in an Azure runbook to send the file as an attachment in an email.